# Python multiprocessing bach insert in Cassandra, no performance improved

Tags: python, cassandra, multiprocessing, batch-insert

I tried batch insert in a single process and multiprocessing, but they used the same time. I didn't get any performance improved. keyspace of cassandra is SimpleStrategy, I think it has only one node. Do these influence?

This is my code for multiprocessing, could you help me find where is wrong?

```
lock = Lock()
ID = Value('i', 0)

def copy(x): 

    cluster = Cluster()
    session = cluster.connect('test')
    global lock, row_ID
    count = 0

    insertt = session.prepare("INSERT INTO table2(id, age, gender, name) values(?, ?, ?, ?)")
    batch = BatchStatement()

    for i in x:
        with open(files[i]) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in tqdm(reader):
                if count <= 59:
                    with lock:
                        ID.value += 1
                    name_ID = row[1]
                    gender_ID = row[2]
                    age_ID = int(row[3])
                    batch.add(insertt, (ID.value, age_ID, gender_ID, name_ID))
                    count += 1
                else: 
                    count = 0
                    with lock:
                        ID.value += 1
                    name_ID = row[1]
                    gender_ID = row[2]
                    age_ID = int(row[3])
                    batch.add(insertt, (ID.value, age_ID, gender_ID, name_ID))
                    session.execute(batch)
                    batch = BatchStatement()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(copy, [range(0,6),range(6,12),range(12,18),range(18,24)])
        end = time.time()
        t = end - start
        print(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Batches are not there to improve performance, opposite really. Logged batches especially (what your using here) is more than 2x the cost of a normal write. An unlogged batch *may* improve performance slightly *if* all the data in the batch belongs in the same partition.

In this particular example your throughput will also be limited to how fast your csv reader can pull from disk. Since its blocking that is probably one of primary impacts to throughput. You can also use executeAsync so you dont block the building of next batch (once again shouldnt use batch here though) on the completion of previous one.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a novice at Cassandra. I have compared the time consumed by using batch(logged) and not using batch both in one process, it actually saves about 4/5 time. But when I add multiprocessing, it has the same performance. So another question is "Did I use multiprocessing in a right way"? And could you please give me some related tutorial links?

Comment: if possible, could you directly correct my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you change from execute to executeasync you will see bigger difference. Reason you see perf improvement with batches is because your throughput is blocked by the latency when using synchronous requests. By reducing the number of requests your reducing blocking latency (littles law fwiw). But the request is actually more expensive and slower that way.

Comment: I just tried execute_async in one process, it really improved the performance, saving 1/3 time. But in multiprocessing, it wasn't improved.

Comment: So the reason for the low speed when I use INSERT without batch is how fast my csv reader can pull from disk, right? If the csv reader fast enough, the batch won't help to increase the insertion speed, right?

Comment: The blocking from the reads to parse the CSV is time you cant do inserts. If you using execute_async your no longer blocking on the time it takes to do the query so really batch or non-batch is irrelevant (more or less) outside of the load it puts on the cluster. As a side note too, the python driver is one of the slowest, and will eventually become a bottleneck. So if you really are trying to maximize the throughput you should probably use the java driver.

Comment: so I just need to change `session.execute(batch)` to `session.execute_async(batch)`, without using `callback`, right?